# Maven not create .class file in target dir

Tags: maven, osgi, maven-bundle-plugin

I am creating osgi bundle by using maven bundle plugin in eclipse.In my application I have non maven jar file on which most of the java classes are depend in my application. my pom.xml file is as follow.

```xml
<build>
    ...

    <plugins>
        ....

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-Activator>org.myapp.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                    <Include-Resource>a1.jar=${basedir}/src/main/java/lib/a1.jar,a2.jar=${basedir}/src/main/java/lib/a2.jar,a3.jar=${basedir}/src/main/java/lib/a3.jar</Include-Resource>
                    <Bundle-ClassPath>.,${basedir}/src/main/java/lib/a1.jar,${basedir}/src/main/java/lib/a2.jar,${basedir}/src/main/java/lib/a3.jar</Bundle-ClassPath>

                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Maven Compiler plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/**</include>
                </includes>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        ....

    </plugins>
</build>
```

By using this I can build my application successfully and my final jar bundle also contains all needed jar files but the **problem is, there is no .class file in the final bundle and my target directory also doesnt contain any .class file.**

If I remove **includes tag** from maven-compiler-plugin then I got class does not exist error.

So please tell me what is the problem with above code **which does not create .class files in target directory and also in final bundle.**

Comment: You should try to start from a very simple pom that works, and then extend it, testing it after every step. That way, you will eventually find the problem.

Comment: OK. I have create sample osgi-archetype project in eclipse with only Activator class and its build successfully but next when **I add import com.abc.pqr** and this package is in the another custom non-maven jar file then I got **package does not exist** error. After that I install my custom jar file by using mvn install:install-file and add dependency also in pom.xml and again build the application but still I got the same error **package does not exist**. So what is the problem.

Comment: At what point do you get the error? Can you post the exact error-message you are getting? Are you sure that the jar you reference actually does contain the package? Please do not post this information in a comment, but rather edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is not very clear, you say it

> contains all needed jar files

However, then you say

> there is no .class file in the final bundle

So it doesn't contain all needed jar files.
Having said that, you seem to be missing the key `export-package` and `private-package` BND directives. Check the documentation of the maven bundle plugin [here](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html)